# Is it possible to cherry pick commits from a repository with different path?

Tags: wordpress, git, cherry-pick

I have 2 repositories: a starter theme repository and a repository for a whole WordPress website.

At the beginning of development, I copied the starter theme to the /web/app/themes/themename in project repository. Then I started developing the site.

Now, there have been some useful changes to the theme that I would like to cherry pick to the starter theme.

But is it possible since the folder structures are different?

Comment: It *might* work. The only way to find out is to try it.

Comment: If you copied the files it won't work as there is no common history from git's POV. To make this work one would usually use a submodule. In this case I'd copy the theme again and commit the changes you want (discard the reest).